# Couldn't find Docker Tool Window IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4 (Ultimate)

Tags: intellij-idea, docker

I am not able to find the `Docker` Tool window on `IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4`

**`Docker Integration`** plugin was already installed on IDE, however, I was not able to find the **`Docker Tool Window`**. I tried to re-installing the **`Docker Integration`** Plugin but no luck.

### How to make Docker Tool Window avaiable?

Version for Docker Integration Plugin: **`2.3.3`**

[image]

---

### EDIT 1

**Docker Clouds config**

[image]

**Docker Registry config**

[image]

**Docker Machine config**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if any other information are needed. I just started learning docker and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plugin ([see documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/docker.html#d190492e23)) still requires prerequisites (it is not a standalone product)

In particular, it does need for docker to be installed first. See "[Docker Installation Windows](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/)".

The [docker tool Windows documentation mentions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/docker-tool-window.html):

> For the tool window to be available, the Docker integration plugin must be installed and at least one Docker configuration must be defined.

Comment: Docker is already installed in my machine and through terminal I am able to run the program as well. I wanted to run it through IDE. Any other steps that I may have missed?

Comment: @AmanTuladhar no (beside what is described in the doc itself). Do you see the views https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/docker-tool-window.html ?

Comment: @AmanTuladhar That view will include the docker configuration that you have to create for the integration to work: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/clouds.html#docker

Comment: No I cannot. I looked at `View > Tool` Windows and was not able to find Docker there

Comment: @AmanTuladhar That means you have not yet declared a docker configuration.

Comment: Docker Configuration ?

Comment: @AmanTuladhar Yes, declare on in IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/clouds.html#docker

Comment: @AmanTuladhar That is what the doc mentions: "Docker configurations. These are named sets of settings for accessing the Docker Remote API." and "Create a Docker configuration. You can do that:

    Separately, in the Settings / Preferences dialog: Ctrl+Alt+S | Build, Execution, Deployment | Clouds | add | Docker.
    When creating a Docker Deployment run configuration: Run | Edit Configurations | add | Docker Deployment, "

Comment: I added the configuration but still I'm not able to find docker tool window. I've updated the question to add config details

Comment: @AmanTuladhar Your cloud section does not have a docker machine.

Comment: @AmanTuladhar You are closer though. The doc (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/docker-tool-window.html) does say: "For the tool window to be available, the Docker integration plugin must be installed and at least one Docker configuration must be defined."

Comment: Thanks @VonC it worked. Now I'm able to find Docker Tool Window

Answer (score 2):

I have at last managed to have it in *IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Ultimate Edition).*

### Steps:

1. Install 'Docker' plugin in intellij
2. View -> Tool Windows -> **Services**
3. At first, 'Docker' options was not there inside the 'Service' menu. I clicked the '+' icon and selected '**Docker Connection**' option.
4. Configured it by selecting 'Docker Machine (default)'. The default option of tcp url was not working. The 'default' docker machine worked.